# Is there a way to compare two doc files that are located online?

Tags: java, file, web

How would I go about comparing two doc files that are download links on a html page? I am currently working in Java. I want to pull two files from two separate URLs then compare them (removing spacing, probably using trim?)

I was also using Watij a bit but I don't think it has that capability.

EDIT: If the webpage has multiple hyperlinks named "Download File", is there a way to list all the URLs without actually knowing them and coding them manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare two files. Open file as input stream and use IOUtils

```
URL url1 = new URL("http://path/file1.txt");
URL url2 = new URL("http://path/file2.txt");
InputStream is1 = url1.openStream();
InputStream is2 = url2.openStream();
if( IOUtils.contentEquals( is1, is2 ) )
{
  //the same content
}
```

Comment: is there a way to see what makes them different?

Comment: There is a library for that https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/ , never used I but I believe that will do the job ...

Comment: I don't see an api for it, and I don't know how to use it as well

Comment: Example https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/wiki/SampleUsage, task 1 seems to match your case